# Custom paypal payment form

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

What I want to do is to store payments via paypal in MySQL database using php. But there are always chances of fail. I mean if customer enters amount and press "pay now" it doesn't mean that customer successfully paid this amount. Customer may simply exit or fail.

This code below is customizable and works like a charm, but there is a problem. The thing is, I can't set callback url with custom variables in following form to get success or fail and store this transaction in my own database.

Any suggestions?

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Teddy Bear">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12.99">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Comment: Store the session data in the database. When the user returns from a successful payment, then update the database accordingly. If fail for whatever reason, don't update the database on return to your site

Comment: @dwhite.me how I'll know that user failed?:)

Comment: Insanely unreliable but a start for a but it now button (you shouldn't really be using these if you want it on a proper store) use the **return** and **cancel_return** vars - see https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0709B__id08A7CI030HS